# cd && ls function doesn't work in other aliases before reloading .bashrc?

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I have the following code in my .bash_aliases:

```
c() { cd "$@" && ls -a ; }
alias cdd="c ~/Downloads"
alias r=". ~/.bashrc"
```

When I load a new terminal, cdd doesn't work before I do the r command. But after doing so, it works as intended. Why is this?

EDIT: .bash_aliases came from installing bash-it. The following code is in my .bashrc:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

I'm using the Terminator terminal on Linux Mint.

Comment: Looks like `bashrc`  is not included in the  `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: @KaushikNayak : In that case `r` should also not work.

Comment: Try putting `c() { cd "$@" && ls -a ; }` in `.bashrc`

Comment: @sjsam : Oh yeah.my bad

Comment: @sjsam That was something I tried doing. I put the function before the call to .bash_aliases, but I still had the same problem.

Comment: Where does `.bash_aliases` get sourced? It's not a standard configuration file. Does your terminal start a login shell or a regular interactive shell?

Comment: Either all of those commands should work or none of them should. Are you sure `r` isn't being defined some where else as well?

Comment: @chepner Added information in the edit. I believe Terminator would be a regular interactive shell? I don't believe `r` is defined anywhere else, and it seems to be working fine anyway?

Comment: If Terminator is like other Mac terminal emulators, it starts a login shell (since the emulator itself isn't started from a shell session, it doesn't inherit an environment from a shell that previously sourced `.bash_profile`). Is there anything in `.bash_profile` that sources either `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`?

Comment: No, my .bash_profile basically just exports PATH and a Java folder.

Comment: @Kevin : Could it be that your alias `r` is also defined in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @user1934428 Nope, it's 3 lines of exports: JAVA_HOME, PATH and QSYS_ROOTDIR.

Comment: In this case, I suggest that you trace the whole login process, to find out why `r` is defined, but `cdd` is not. I would put at the very start of your .bash_profile a `set -x`, followed by an `alias` command, which shows you which aliases are defined initially (if any). Then open a new terminal window. From this output, you should see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked [this same question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420581/cd-ls-function-doesnt-work-in-other-aliases-before-reloading-bashrc) on the Unix Stack Exchange and found a fix. "c" was already mapped to clear initially on launch and thus wasn't working until `.bash_aliases` was reloaded. Upon changing the function from "c" to "d", everything worked from launch.

Comment: Then this question should be closed as unreproducible as your question doesn't contain anything to let us in on this configuration problem and since this is apparently a cross-site duplicate.